# How to write mongoose query to combine data from two model's?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Technology: MongoDB, ExpressJS

I have 3 schema

1. userSchema:

```
userSchema = {
  name: {type: String},
  password: {type: String},
  email: {type: String},
  friends: {type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId]}
}
```

2. textPostSchema =

```
textPostSchema = {
   text: {type: String},
   postType: {type: String, default: "textPost"},
   userId: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId}
}
```

3. articalPostSchema:

```
articalPostSchema = {
  title: {type: String},
  content: {type: String}
  postType: {type: String, default: "articalPost"},
  userId: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId}
}
```

now I have one social media application in which I have to show these two post when user's friend post's a post, and include infinite scroll. Both `textPost` and `articalPost` should be send if  to frontend and only total 10 post should be sent at a time. How should I write a API for timeline?

**output** should look like:

```
{
  post: [
          {
           title: "artical Post title", 
           content: "artical post content", 
           postType: "articalPost", 
           userId: "60b9c9801a2a2547de643ccd"
          },
          {
           text: "text post ", 
           postType: "textPost", 
           userId: "60b9c9801a2a2547de643ccd"
          }, 
          ... 8 more
        ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I got the solution:-
I created on more schema:

```
timelineSchema = {
    postId: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: function () {
        switch (this.postCategoryType) {
          case 'articleposts':
            return 'ArticlePost';
          case 'textposts':
            return 'TextPost';
        }
      },
    },
    postCategoryType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
```

and then I created one function to get only friends post:

```
exports.getTimelinePosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const timelinePosts = await TimelineModel.find({
      userId: { $in: [...req.user.friends, req.params.id] },
    })
      .skip((req.params.page - 1) * 10)
      .limit(10)
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .populate('postId');
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', data: timelinePosts });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: you want to combine article post schema and text post schema in a post object?

Comment: @AbuSayeedMondal yes you can say that every time when I call API to get post then API should respond with next 10 post, and these 10 post should belong to either textPost or articlePost or from both according to ```createdTime```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the pagination with Mongoose, You can do something like that.

```
const getPosts = async (userId, pageNumber) => {
  let result = await Post.find({ userId })
    .skip((pageNumber - 1) * 10)
    .limit(10);

  return result;
};
```

`pageNumber` is a counter that you need to pass from the frontend and will be incremented by 1 whenever a user hits the scroll limit.

If you want to query and merge data from multiple collections you need to update your schema to use `populate`. Just include `ref` where you are referring to other collections.

This may help.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: thanks Uddesh, let me implement this, if everything goes well I let you know!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using express and mongoose. The code to fetch both,

```
// first bring all those schema from your mongoose models
const Article = require('./models/ArticleSchema');
const Text = require('./models/TextSchema');

const fetchArticleAndTextPost = async (req, res)=>{
    //find all data 
    const articles = await Article.find();
    const texts = await Text.find();

    //join them together
    const post = articles.concat(texts);

    return res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        data: post,
    })

}
```

Comment: I want to create api which send 10 post at a time in this it will concat all post and send back data to frontend. What if we have 10000's of article post and 10000's of text post then this code complexity is too high. And we cannot splice our array after ```concat``` because we need only 10 post after previous ones so remaining data is useless. Is there any way in which we can only extract 10 post at a time from two models ?